# How do I make a C++ program that reads info in an array of strings and then sorts it into a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class

More specifically, I need to take a list formatted as

```
const string studentData[4] =
 {"A1,John,Smith,John1989@gmail.com,20,30,35,40,SECURITY",
 "A2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,50,30,40,NETWORK",
 "A3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,20,40,33,SOFTWARE",
 "A4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,50,58,40,SECURITY"}
```

And put them all into an array of a class wherein it is formatted as

```
class student {
public:
   void getter();
   void setter();

private:
   string ID;
   string firstName;
   string lastName;
   string email;
   int age;
   int courseDays[3];
   degree; //degree is an enumerated data type defined in another file.
}
```

I then need to, from a separate file, use an array of pointers that is a private element of another class to perform several other functions. Predominantly, I don't know how to separate the individual datapoints in each string such that they can be set as the values for the private variables of the "student" class.

Comment: You already have a character string containing the data. There are *formatted-input* functions (`sscanf` in `cstdio` header) that will make that trivial. Otherwise, you can create a `stringstream` from the buffer and use `getline` with a delimiter of `','`. While `degree` may be an ennumerated type, you will need an instance of that type, e.g. `degree deg;` instead of attempting to assign directly to the type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stream and `getline` to split the string on commas:

```
std::istringstream is{"A1,John,Smith"}; // for example
std::getline(is, ID, ',');
std::getline(is, first_name, ',');
std::getline(is, last_name, '\0');
```

For integers, just read in the number and discard the comma:

```
is >> age;
is.ignore(1);
```